# Start with fresh copy of node, npm and cordova

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ionic-framework, yo

I had a makeshift setup on Lubuntu that 'functioned' with sudo npm install. I used Ionic Framework generator to create projects and they functioned as well as the builds and deployment.
I upgraded to 15.04 and ever since had problems finding a solution that worked does not give EACCESS errors or grunt serve telling me

> Upgrade warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
> it is highly suggested to upgrade the following:
>
> Please update your Node runtime to version  >=0.12.x
> Please update your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

then for npm install -g cordova to tell me

> npm WARN engine cordova-serve@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":">= 0.12.0","npm":">= 2.5.1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.26","npm":"2.12.1"})

I have tried the "chown -R `whoami` /dir/of/npm"
I have delete npm, node install brew and created new installs for all.
I still get EACCESS errors, my yo ionic "grunt serve" deploys the browser but gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I installed brew, manually deleted the npm folder and did a clean install. No joy

> which node - /home/username/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/node
>
> node -v v0.10.26
>
> which npm - /home/userna/.linuxbrew/bin/npm
>
> npm -v 2.12.1
>
> which cordova - /usr/local/bin/cordova
>
> cordova -v 3.5.0-0.2.6

And for good meassure i thought if i installed node4 all my troubles would disappear.

I know i messed this up but i would like a clean start with node, npm(without sudo) and cordova. Any help would be appreciated

Ps: I have done most of the normal suggestions hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed node using nvm? 
So try

```
nvm use 4.0.0
```

In general:

```
nvm install [VERSION]
nvm use [VERSION]
```

To use permanent:

```
nvm alias default [VERSION]
```

try also to install cordova again after updating node

```
npm install -g cordova
```

If all fails:

Uninstall node and reinstall propper using `brew`:

```
cd ~
sudo rm -rf .npm
brew update
brew uninstall npm
brew install npm
```

Comment: I used brew to install node and nvm. I'll update nvm to 4.0.0 and see if there is a change.

Comment: should work. I updated my answer, because on some systems nvm "forgets" on terminal restart what's the current version, so you should set one as default.

Comment: Thanks for you answers @abimelex, but all the errors still persist after implementing your suggestions

Comment: mh what gives you `node -v` ? If it's still not 4.0.0 reinstall it as mentioned above.

Comment: node -v v0.12.7

Everything is still the same.

grunt serve within my dir repsonds with 
ERROR
Warning: Unable to delete "www/bower_components" file (EACCES,